# Unable to retrieve tagged photo info using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm having a hard time running this FQL query.

```
SELECT pid, src_big FROM photo WHERE pid 
IN (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me())
```

The photo_tag table returns a pid that is a much longer string than the usual photo pid.

The inner SELECT statement returns the right number of tagged photos. However, I'd like to get more info on those photos. Any ideas?

Comment: HELP! Tried everything, still the same result :(

Answer (score 1):

which info do you need? if you want more infos, here is the full list of data you can get from the photo table:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/

about the pid: yes, that is not the "real" photo id. i think you have to select the column "object_id" for the real id.
"The pid is unique only for a given user." - so you cannot really work with it anyway, i guess.

just include those columns from my link you need, like this:

```
SELECT pid, src_big, object_id FROM photo...
```